# Delphi to PPT- How to Copy then Move a Slide

Tags: delphi, com, powerpoint

Delphi RIO - I am using Delphi to control PPT.  I need to copy a given slide to the END of the PPT deck, and then make changes to it.  I copy my slide via the slide.DUPLICATE method.  This creates a copy of the slide after the source slide.  I have found the [MoveTo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sliderange.moveto), but it does not appear to be a valid method within Delphi. I have Office_TLB, MSPpt2000 in my USES clause.  I have tried to import a more recent TYPE library for PPT, but there does appear to be one. (Method attempted:  From Delphi/ Component / Import Component / Type Library.)  How do I move a slide (or a slide range object, since that is what the DUPLICATE command returns) to the end of the deck?  Here is my current code.  Everything here works... I just don't have the Move operation...

```
procedure CopySlide;
var
  lDeck: PowerPointPresentation;
  lApplication: PowerPointApplication;
  lSourceSlide : PowerPointSlide;
  lDestSlideRange: SlideRange;

  begin
    lApplication := CoPowerPointApplication.Create;

    // Open the PPT Deck
   lDeck := lApplication.Presentations.Open('D:\testppt.pptx', msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue);
   lSourceSlide := lDeck.Slides.Item(4);

   // Copy the slide.  Duplicate returns a SlideRange, not a slide object
   lDestSlideRange := lSourceSlide.Duplicate;

   // Move the slide to the end of the deck
   // ?????
  end;
```

Comment: Where did you get this `MSPpt2000` unit from? Delphi ships with MS Office type libraries located in `OCX\Servers` in installation directory. Power Point TLB is in `PowerPoint2010.pas`. `SlideRange` interface contains method `MoveTo` imported as `procedure MoveTo(toPos: SYSINT); safecall;`. I also tried importing TLB manually and the method was present. I suspect you just reference wrong unit. NB: to move cloned slide to the last position you use `lDestSlideRange.MoveTo(lDeck.Slides.Count)`.

Comment: Peter,  that was the culprit.  Submit as answer and I will accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi ships with multiple MS Office type libraries (located in `OCX\Servers` in Delphi installation directory) to support [legacy MS Office versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Office#Office_versions). Type libraries for PowerPoint are:

- `MSPpt2000.pas` - Office 2000 (9.0)
- `PowerPointXP.pas` - Office XP (10.0)
- `PowerPoint2010.pas` - Office 2010 (14.0)

You picked the oldest one which doesn't support the method.

### Option 1

Pick newer version - at least Office XP (10.0). That would also mean dropping support for Office 2000. Then you would be able to use `MoveTo` method:

```
lDestSlideRange.MoveTo(lDeck.Slides.Count);
```

### Option 2

Emulate Move to with [`Cut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sliderange.cut) and [`Paste`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.paste):

```
lDestSlideRange.Cut;
lDeck.Slides.Paste(lDeck.Slides.Count + 1);
```

Method `Slides.Paste` takes index of slide (1-based) before which the clipboard content is pasted. For conveniece you can use `-1` as index to paste the content at the end.

```
lDestSlideRange.Cut;
lDeck.Slides.Paste(-1);
```